How do I create a new partition on a DELL PowerEdge T140 server that already has Ubuntu 24.04 server OS installed?
Recently, I installed Ubuntu 24.04 server on a DELL PowerEdge T440 server, which has three HDDs, each with 1.2 TB. Currently, it has one partition. I need to create two more partitions excluding the default partition. How can I do this?"
Would you like a step-by-step guide on how to create the additional partitions?

More details needed. How were the drives setup raid, single drives ? Why two more? What would they be used for?

It's currently have only one drive raid.

For user space, need to storing data seperately in some other drivers...

This question is similar to: How do I add this extra partition to my installed Ubuntu system?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Make sure drives are gpt partitioned. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive & http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html & http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html
